# Keep only duplicated rows with a subset

Tags: python-polars

I have a dataframe that I'd like to explore and look only the duplicated rows based on two or more columns.

For example:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"A": [1, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6],
                   "B": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "C", "A"],
                 "C": [2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]})
```

I'd like to return duplicate combination for columns A and B only. I've tried:

```
df.filter(pl.col(["A", "B"]).is_duplicated()) # Returns: This is ambiguous. Try to combine the predicates with the 'all' or `any' expression.
```

When adding .all() in between, the result is the same as above

```
df.filter(pl.col(["A", "B"]).all().is_duplicated()) # Same as above
```

Unique with keep "none" returns the opposite result I'd like to have, so tried the below:

```
df.unique(subset=["A", "B"], keep="none").is_not() # 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'is_not'
```

Expected output would be to see only the rows:

```
[5, "C", 2]
[5, "C", 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a [`.struct`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.struct.html#polars.struct) is how to group multiple expressions together as a "single entity".

You can then use [`.is_duplicated`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.is_duplicated.html#polars-expr-is-duplicated)

```
df.filter(pl.struct(["A", "B"]).is_duplicated())
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A   | B   | C   │
│ --- | --- | --- │
│ i64 | str | i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 5   | C   | 2   │
│ 5   | C   | 1   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

---

Passing multiple items to `.col()`

```
pl.col(["A", "B"]).is_duplicated()
```

is the equivalent of

```
pl.col("A").is_duplicated(), pl.col("B").is_duplicated()
```

Which is why the struct step is needed:

```
>>> df.select(pl.struct(["A", "B"]))
shape: (6, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ A         │
│ ---       │
│ struct[2] │
╞═══════════╡
│ {1,"A"}   │
│ {6,"B"}   │
│ {5,"C"}   │
│ {4,"D"}   │
│ {5,"C"}   │
│ {6,"A"}   │
└───────────┘
```

Comment: I really loved your solution, how can I understand the Struct functionalities better? What should I be searching for? I can't find the applications clearly on the documentation.

Comment: I think I found a better link: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/custom_functions.html?highlight=struct#combining-multiple-column-values - does that help?

Comment: I wanted something more in-depth, in fact I needed to better understand the use case for the struct, there's also the fact that you can name the struct's fields... I really wanted to understand the application in depth...
But thanks anyway :)

Comment: They're like a dict, you can use `.unnest()` with them e.g. when dealing with JSON: `df = pl.DataFrame({"json": ["""{"foo":{"bar":[1,2,3]}}"""]}).with_columns(pl.col("json").str.json_extract()).unnest("json")`

Comment: Thanks, I will try to poke it, it might be handy for me thank you. Polars have the best community ever :D

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation we have the following example:

Examples

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 2, 3, 1],
        "b": ["x", "y", "z", "x"],
    }
)
df.is_duplicated()
shape: (4,)
Series: '' [bool]
[
        true
        false
        false
        true
]
```

This mask can be used to visualize the duplicated lines like this:

```
df.filter(df.is_duplicated())
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ x   │
│ 1   ┆ x   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.is_duplicated.html#polars.DataFrame.is_duplicated